# How to measure the response time including rendering time in Loadrunner?

Tags: loadrunner

Am I correct in assuming the transaction response time reported (when using HTTP protocol) by Loadrunner does not include the rendering time and it is only the absolute response time (from the user click to till he gets a response from the server)? If I want to include the rendering time also, from a user perspective, how do I measure it?

Answer (score 1):

A GUI Virtual User will grab 100% of the time, including the actual paint to the client screen.  A Truclient virtual user will measure everything except the "Paint" on the screen in the graphic below from the Chrome Browser Developer tools

[image]

So, you can take GUI - API level (HTTP) vritual user to measure the cost (Login_GUI-Login_HTTP), or Truclient-HTTP (Login_TC-Login_HTTP) to measure the cost of the client less the actual paint to the screen.

Note: GUI virtual users have been an available option since 1996 when paired with API.  GUI Virtual Users were actually the first type of virtual users in 1993/4.  Truclient for about five years.   So, the answer is, "Yes, a path exists....and you have two paths."

However, given the amount of time between performance testing and deployment there is often zero time left to adjust the client architecture to improve performance when you do find issues with a release.  You are far better off to be adopting the Agile and DevOps models where everyone is responsible for asking questions about quality, including performance and security.   The tools to perform extensive client performance audits are available inside of every modern browser.  If the client code fails the built in audits for performance when it arrives to be performance tested then just start writing defects on every item listed in the audits and bounce it back to the devs and functional testers with the path on how they may run the audits themselves.